# Error with: using System.Data;

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using, system.data

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
...
```

I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop

Comment: Are you sure you add `System.Data.dll` as a reference to your project?

Comment: Well, *are* you missing an assembly reference? Have you added the reference to your project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing assembly reference. You need to add assembly reference.

Check out following images.

[image]

Go to soution explorer right click on references and select Add Reference.

then Select System.Data assemly reference.[image]

That's it.

Press ok.

Press F6 to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Solution Explorer` window of Visual Studio right click on your project, and click `Add Reference`. There you can add assembly reference which are sometimes needed to use certain namespaces (like System.Data).

Answer (score 0):

view > Object browser
then select System.Data
then add references in selected project
[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXsl2.jpg)